# Application has been deleted

Tags: facebook-apps

My brother has a facebook application, which is running for more than a month with lots of daily users. When we checked on today, the developer dashboard doesn't show the app. And it doesn't even list the app name in the list of apps (left pane of the dashboard).

When we checked the error_log in the server, the last message is:

> [15-Oct-2012 22:28:31 UTC] OAuthException: Error validating application. Application has been deleted.

Why Facebook automatically deleted the app? Or is it due to some glitch in the Facebook server? How do we contact Facebook team to investigate about this?

Or, creating a new app with the same name and other details would be the only solution to this?

Any hints or ideas about this issue?

Comment: When was this app developed ?

Comment: Facebook does delete apps for the users if it does not follow the guidelines set for developing apps during review. Sometimes if the app is just sitting there without much hit on it, then also it is deleted as an inactive app. When an app is developed, it generates an unique id for the user, using which the app can be used. Are you sure that this app is not working it wherever you had previously embedded it ? If it's working, then it's quite possible they have move it to some other place, without hampering your application .

Comment: But it was a popular app. He just checked the mail and found that there was notification saying the app has been restricted. But no info was given that the app has been deleted ! They do without notice ?

Comment: Was the app used some where ? If so, is it still working ?

Comment: We didn't changed anything recently. And was working till yesterday. All of a sudden it got removed. Also, this app wasn't restricted before! This is the first time getting a notification.

Comment: The app is an FB canvas app. It's used inside the apps.facebook.com domain.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18102/discussion-between-the-dark-knight-and-akhilesh-b-chandran)

Comment: Hi Akhilesh is your application recovered or not. If yes the is your application settings come as it is as earlier or you did it again after recovery of your facebook application.

Comment: No I didn't got the app back. I believe it got deleted because of violating a terms and condition which I was unaware that time. I mean like automatically posting the photo to the user. And thereby the users might have been deleting the pics, which marks a negative point on the app. And I believe FB automatically deleted or something. Right now, they have implemented many security stuff like manually reviewing of the app for certain permissions, etc. It's hard to maintain FB apps as FB frequently changes many things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are an owner of the app, you can go to https://developers.facebook.com/appeal
There will be an restricted app you can appeal for. And you can see there reasons why your app has been restricted. 
Like this:

> Our automated systems have flagged your app NNN (123) for receiving a
>   high amount of negative user feedback.
>
> Please check out the
>   following common issues regarding your app's restriction.
>
> - Only publish or tag photos after receiving explicit consent from the user (FPP IV.3)

Comment: Hi, Grin, my facebook app has been deleted by Facebook because of violating Facebook platform policy. Now I have make some changes to my app and remove all contents that violate Facebook platform policy. Can I get it back? Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Bloodwolf. I'm sorry, I can't help you. We have not been able to restore our app. Besides, it was almost 3 years ago, facebook policy definitely has changed since. Wish you luck

Answer (score 1):

facebook tends to delete apps that, for example, dont have a privacy policy or terms of service. I would go about and contact facebook about this. They'll be able to tell you more. good luck!

Comment: Can you please tell me how to contact them ? I just checked their support page and doesn't found any email id to their support team.

Comment: Yeah, hopefully that will help you. Best of luck .